# How to make NHibernate 5 ConventionModelMapper map ICollection as Set by default

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have some existing models written and I was trying to map them with NHibernate (version 5). As it happened, they are properties exposed as `IEnumerable<T>` with backing fields declared as `ICollection<T>`, like so:

```cs
    public class Encounter
    {
        public virtual String Title { get; protected set; } = null!;
        public virtual IEnumerable<Conversation> Conversations => _conversations.AsEnumerable();
        private ICollection<Conversation> _conversations = new HashSet<Conversation>();
        protected Encounter() { }
        // ...
    }
```

I'm trying to use `ConventionModelMapper` as much as possible, and so far so good, but I found it doesn't seem to know what to do with `ICollection<T>`, and I get `TransientObjectException`s when it tries to persist objects in those collections. If I change them to `ISet<T>`s, it maps by convention just fine... but it seems like this should be something I should be able to easily tell the `ConventionModelMapper` to do, since I have a number of these `ICollection<T>` members.

I'm not finding an easy way... This is part of the way there, but overrides the existing `IsSet()` logic, so I'd have to add back in conditions for `ISet` members at least, and it doesn't work for my `IEnumerable<T>` properties with backing fields (which NH is clearly able to deal with because it correctly picks up `ISet` backing fields)...

```cs
    var mapper = new ConventionModelMapper();
    mapper.IsSet((memberInfo, b1) =>
    {
        var memberType = memberInfo.GetPropertyOrFieldType();
        if (memberType.IsGenericType)
        {
            return memberType.GetGenericInterfaceTypeDefinitions().Contains(typeof(ICollection<>));
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Seems like this should be simpler, am I missing an event hook?

Answer (score 0):

After some further experimentation and research, I came up with this, that works... but it seems overwrought and not very DRY. Before I refactor this, someone please tell me there's a better way?

```cs
// All this just to get NHibernate to map ICollection as "Set" by default?
mapper.IsSet((memberInfo, b1) =>
{
    IEnumerable<Type> typeDefs;
    Type memberType = memberInfo.GetPropertyOrFieldType();
    if (memberType.IsGenericType)
    {
        typeDefs = memberType.GetGenericInterfaceTypeDefinitions();
        if(typeDefs.Contains(typeof(ISet<>)) || typeDefs.Contains(typeof(ICollection<>)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    const BindingFlags defaultBinding = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
    var fieldInfo = (from ps in PropertyToField.DefaultStrategies.Values
        let fi = memberInfo.DeclaringType.GetField(ps.GetFieldName(memberInfo.Name), defaultBinding)
        where fi != null
        select fi).FirstOrDefault();
    if (fieldInfo != null)
    {
        memberType = fieldInfo.GetPropertyOrFieldType();
        if (memberType.IsGenericType)
        {
            typeDefs = memberType.GetGenericInterfaceTypeDefinitions();
            if (typeDefs.Contains(typeof(ISet<>)) || typeDefs.Contains(typeof(ICollection<>)))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

This is near-copypasta and uses code from NHibernate and its included [PropertyToField](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Mapping/ByCode/PropertyToField.cs) utility class. I mostly understand it, but it's just... verbose... seems like there should be a better option. Again, am I missing a simple hook somewhere?